# Buzzing noise when headphones plugged in motherboard sound ports on Windows PC

Tags: windows, audio, microphone, speakers

I'm a heavy user of the StackOverflow community, and after a bit of research I found that this is the StackExchange community that might help me out.

I've been bought a headset that has 2 3.5mm jacks, HiFi, one is the actual speakers on the headset, the other one is the microphone. Here's a bit of a breakdown of the problem:

**On the PC(Windows 10):**

I plug in the headphones only -- slight buzzing noise. When I start an application, whether it's a game or an IDE, the buzzing is louder.

I plug in the headphones PLUS mic, the buzzing gets really loud. Even louder when I open anything else.

**On my Dell Monitor (which has an audio-in/out)**

I plug in the headphones -- no buzzing noise. No buzzing noise when I start any application.

I plug in the mic (in the pc) while the headphones are plugged in the Monitor, again loud buzzing noise.

**What I've tried**

My PC power supply cable was plugged in an extension cable with some other components. I thought it might be a grounding issue, so I unplugged it and plugged it into its separate socket. Did not solve my problem.

What else can I try? At the moment my headphones are plugged in in the monitor and I don't have any problems. But sometimes I would like to use my mic as well. Any ideas?

Regards,

Comment: So the ground is 100% good now? Sometimes old buildings without a ground get a new outlet installed, but don't actually have a ground

Comment: @Xen2050 do you have an idea how to test if it's the grounding?

Comment: PCs tend to be electrically noisy in a way that affects analog sound.  One computer can be noisier than another.  You can improve it by looking at the grounding, shielding, and plug connections.  But even if those are good, there are often many sources of electrical noise that get picked up and amplified in the audio system.

Comment: There's little plug-in [receptacle testers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receptacle_tester) with OK lights, or a multimeter works even better too. I'm not sure if it's the real problem though, but good to check anyway. Maybe try (temporarily) turning off anything else electrical nearby (in the room, on same circuit, or more) and see if anything changes. I've got a halogen lamp that interferes with everything when it turns on. Or maybe the headphone jack or plug's dirty

Comment: Lots of similar Q's on this site too, just search for [audio static](https://superuser.com/search?q=audio+static) or headphone static. Maybe not similar enough to be  a duplicate, looks like it's always different hardware